# Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney critical values in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have noticed that when I try to find the critical values for the Mann-Whitney U using R, the values are always 1+critical value. For example, for $\alpha=.05, n = 10, m = 5$, the (two-tailed) critical value is 8, while for $\alpha=.05, n=12, m=8$, the (two-tailed) critical value is 22 (check the [tables](http://www.lesn.appstate.edu/olson/stat_directory/Statistical%20procedures/Mann_Whitney%20U%20Test/Mann-Whitney%20Table.pdf)), but:

```
> qwilcox(.05/2,10,5)
[1] 9
> qwilcox(.05/2,12,8)
[1] 23
```

Of course I'm not considering something, but... anyone could explain me why?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think that the answer here might be that you're comparing apples and oranges.

Let $F(x)$ denote the cdf of the Mann-Whitney $U$ statistic. `qwilcox` is the quantile function $Q(\alpha)$ of $U$. By definition, it is therefore
$$Q(\alpha)=\inf \{x\in \mathbb{N}: F(x)\geq \alpha\},\qquad \alpha\in(0,1).$$

Because $U$ is discrete, there is usually no $x$ such that $F(x)=\alpha$, so typically $F(Q(\alpha))>\alpha$.

Now, consider the critical value $C(\alpha)$ for the test. In this case, you want $F(C(\alpha))\leq \alpha$, since you otherwise will have a test with a [type I error rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors#Type_I_error) that is *larger* than the nominal one. This is usually considered to be undesirable; *conservative* tests tend to be prefered. Hence,
$$C(\alpha)=\sup \{x\in \mathbb{N}: F(x)\leq \alpha\},\qquad \alpha\in(0,1).$$
Unless there is an $x$ such that $F(x)=\alpha$, we therefore have $C(\alpha)=Q(\alpha)-1$.

The reason for the discrepancy is that `qwilcox` has been designed to compute quantiles and not critical values!

Comment: (+1) Good, simple, concise description. :)

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the rank sum test statistic is discrete and so you need to use a critical value such that the tail probability is $\geq$ to the specified $\alpha$.  For some sample sizes equal to alpha cannot be achieved and that is my guess as to why you need the +1.

Comment: So why is +1 needed in R and not in the usual tables?

Comment: Yes, but `.0236723` is a more precise approximation to $\alpha/2$ than `.02868937`, so it has no sense to return the quantile 23.

Comment: @this.is.not.a.nick: perhaps more importantly, $0.0236723<0.025$ whereas $0.02868937>0.025$, which means that in the former case the actual significance level will be $<0.05$ and that in the latter it will be $>0.05$. Usually people tend to prefer to err on the right side, i.e. to have a lower significance level than the nominal one (meaning that the values from the tables are preferable).

Comment: Right to both Procrastinator and MansT.  Actually the definiton of significance level requires that the tail probabilities do not sum to anything higher than alpha.  I talk about this in my paper with Christine Liu on the sawtoothed behavior of the power function for exact binomial tests via the Clopper-Pearson method (see American Statistician (2002)).

Comment: @MichaelChernick So, in this case is the R method for computing critical values opinable?

Comment: R and the tables for the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test should agree bu where did the OP get his tables?  Would they be the same in Hollander and Wolfe's book?

Comment: @Michael: I think that the reason for the discrepancy is that quantiles and critical values are different things in this case. I tried to explain it in a separate answer!

Comment: @MansT Where is your separate answer?  The comment above does not explain it.  The tables should follow the standard definition of significance level. You can't claim an exact significance level of 0.05 if the tail probabilities total to anything higher than0.05.

Comment: @Michael: [It's on the same page as this one.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32445/wilcoxon-mann-whitney-critical-values-in-r/32451#32451) The tables follow the standard defintion, which means that the critical values aren't quantiles.

Comment: @MansT Okay I see the quantile for alpha must be the first value exceeding alpha while the critical value for an alpha (left-sided case) must be the largest value so that the left tail  will be less than alpha.  These numbers will be equal on rare occasions but usually the quantile will be 1 integer higher.  Still statistical tables are generated for hyptothesis testing.  So I don't think they should be reporting these quantiles which are not what the user actually needs.

Comment: @Michael: Agreed. In some sense, `qwilcox` does what it's supposed to do, but not what you'd expect it do to.