# Critical value for Wilcoxon one-sample signed-rank test in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, wilcoxon-signed-rank, tables

I am trying to find the critical value for the Wilcoxon one-sample signed-rank test. Currently, I can find the value using tables. I looked at `qwilcox()` in R, but it appears that this gives the critical values for the Wilcoxon two-sample test (or Mann–Whitney test). Is there a function in `R` which I can use to compute this critical value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `qsignrank()` function. Example:

```
> qsignrank(.025, 10, lower.tail=FALSE)
46
```

This means that for a sample size of 10 and a *two-sided* test with a significance level of 5%, the test statistic must be greater than 46 (i.e., 47 or greater) to be statistically significant. Example data:

```
> set.seed(1)
> x = rnorm(10, .5)
> wilcox.test(x)

    Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  x
V = 47, p-value = 0.04883
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0
```

Here the test statistic is 47, and significant at the 5% level.

Note that for a two-sided test, the test statistic returned by `qsignrank()` is the *larger* of the two possible test statistics. For example, `wilcox.test(-x)` gives a test statistic of 8, which can be transformed into 47 by $\frac{10\cdot 11}{2}-8$.

Comment: I guess we have to subtract 1 from the result of `qsignrank` in order to obtain the critical value.. As mentioned here -http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32445/wilcoxon-mann-whitney-critical-values-in-r